# Set a matrix on bitmap

Tags: android, bitmap

Hy, 
I want set only matrix in this code but if i use this statemant , it reset all drawing picture.

Bitmap a= Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);

a need only new matrix but how i get it

Comment: why do you want to set a matrix on a bitmap?

Answer (score 1):

I want only:

```
public static Bitmap flip(Bitmap src, int type) {

    // create new matrix for transformation

    Matrix matrix = new Matrix();

    // if vertical

    if(type == FLIP_VERTICAL) {

        // y = y * -1

        matrix.preScale(1.0f, -1.0f);

    }


    // if horizonal

    else if(type == FLIP_HORIZONTAL) {

        // x = x * -1

       matrix.preScale(-1.0f, 1.0f);

    // unknown type

    } else {

        return null;

    }

    // return transformed image
   //Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);
  Bitmap pp= Bitmap.createBitmap(src, 0, 0, src.getWidth(), src.getHeight(), matrix, true);

  return pp;

}
```

If oyu saw this Bitmao pp= ...
I want only change src ->matrix and that is all